# Result set stored in hashMap giving zero row count

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

I have two methods in my class, First I am calling method `dbExecuteStatement()`, which execute the sql query. After execution of sql query, I get a ResultSet object. I am saving this ResultSet object in a static hashMap, so that on my next method call `fetchResults()`, I can use the existing result set to retrieve the results. Reason for saving the ResultSet object in a map is ,in `fetchResults()` method request parameter, I will get the max fetch row size, and on basis of that value I will be iterating the result set.  Both of this methods are supposed to be called individual from the client side.

Now the problem, I am facing is that, When I am iterating the ResultSet object in `fetchResults()` method, I am getting the row count zero. If I fetch the same ResultSet from a hashMap in `dbExecuteStatement()`, I get the actual row count i.e 5 in my case. I checked the ResultSet object that I have put in the hash map in `fetchResults()` method and `dbExecuteStatement()`, it is the same object. But If get the `ResultSetMetaData` object in `fetchResults()` method and `dbExecuteStatement()`, they are coming different. Can someone help me in understanding the cause, Why I am getting the result count zero.

Below is the code:

```
  public class HiveDao1 {
    private static Map<Object,Map<Object,Object>> databaseConnectionDetails 
        = new HashMap<Object,Map<Object,Object>>();

    //This method will execute the sql query and will save the ResultSet obj in a hashmap for later use
     public void dbExecuteStatement(DbExecuteStatementReq dbExecuteStatementReq){
      //I already have a connection object saved in map
      String uniqueIdForConnectionObject = dbExecuteStatementReq.getDbUniqueConnectionHandlerId();
      Map<Object,Object> dbObject = databaseConnectionDetails.get(uniqueIdForConnectionObject);
      Connection connection = (Connection) dbObject.get(DatabaseConstants.CONNECTION);

      try {

    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement() ;
        // Execute the query
    ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(dbExecuteStatementReq.getStatement().trim()) ;

    //save the result set for further use, Result set will be used in fetchResult() call
    dbObject.put(DatabaseConstants.RESULTSET, resultSet);

    /*
     * Now below is the debugging code,which I put to compare the result set
     *  iteration dbExecuteStatement() and fetchResults method
     */
    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) dbObject.get(DatabaseConstants.RESULTSET);

    ResultSetMetaData md = (ResultSetMetaData) dbObject.get(DatabaseConstants.RESULTSETMETADATA);

     System.out.println("==ResultSet fethced in dbExecuteStatement=="+rs);
     System.out.println("==ResultSet metadata fetched in dbExecuteStatement ==="+rs.getMetaData());

    int count = 0;
    while (rs.next()) {
        ++count;
    }

     if (count == 0) {
        System.out.println("No records found");
    }

    System.out.println("No of rows found from result set in dbExecuteStatement is "+count);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

     /*
      * This method fetch the result set object from hashMap
      * and iterate it on the basis of fetch size received in req parameter
      */
public void fetchResults(FetchResultsReq fetchResultsReq){

    String uniqueIdForConnectionObject = fetchResultsReq.getDbUniqueConnectionHandlerId();
    Map<Object,Object> dbObject = databaseConnectionDetails.get(uniqueIdForConnectionObject);

    try {
        //Fetch the ResultSet object that was saved by dbExecuteStatement()
        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) dbObject.get(DatabaseConstants.RESULTSET);
        ResultSetMetaData md = (ResultSetMetaData) dbObject.get(DatabaseConstants.RESULTSETMETADATA);

        System.out.println("ResultSet fethced in fetchResults at server side dao layer======"+rs);
        System.out.println("ResultSet metadata fetched in fetchResults at server side dao layer======"+md);

       int count = 0;
       while (rs.next()) {
           ++count;
        }

        if (count == 0) {
         System.out.println("No records found");
        }
        //Here the row count is not same as row count in dbExecuteStatement()            
        System.out.println("No of rows found from result set in fetchResults is "+count);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible that `String uniqueIdForConnectionObject = dbExecuteStatementReq.getDbUniqueConnectionHandlerId();` returns different values in two methods? It seems you are getting Map using that unique-id and it may be returning two different maps.

Comment: Two questions - 1. Is HiveDao1 class singleton? 2. Can you attach the code where you are calling fetchResults method?

Comment: No, I checked , I am using the same key, for retrieving the map.

Comment: @TechnoCrat, No it is not singleton, it is actually a dao layer, I have a service layer when I have exposed two services one for executeStatement and other for fetchResults. This services are actually invoked step by step from client side.

Comment: Are you calling `fetchResults` from within `dbExecuteStatement`? If not, the `Statement` and the `Connection` to which the `ResultSet` is attached will close when they go out of scope at the end of the `dbExecuteStatement` and that will result in the `ResultSet` being closed as well.

Comment: (a) Note that your debug test causes the result set cursor to move to the end so any following fetches will not work. (b) Does your problem (assuming you remove the debug part) also happen if you call the two methods immediately one after the other?

Comment: @Glenn Note that they will not close immediately, only when they are finalized.

Comment: @RealSkeptic , I removed the result set iteration code from execute statement method, as it was a test code to compare the result, I was able to get the right row count from the result set in fetchResults. Thank you so much. One last question I have, result set object can be fetched only once??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment (And @Glenn's):

**Using a `ResultSet` more than once**

When you write debug code that iterates a `ResultSet`, the cursor moves to the end of the results. Of course, if you then call the same object and use `next()`, it will still be at the end, so you won't get any more records.

If you really need to read from the same `ResultSet` more than once, you need to execute the query such that it returns a scrollable `ResultSet`. You do this when you create the statement:

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement( 
                              ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                              ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY );
```

The default statement created by `connection.createStatement()` without parameters returns a result set of type `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`, and that `ResultSet` object can only be read once.

If your result set type is scroll insensitive or scroll sensitive, you can use a statement like `rs.first()` to reset the cursor and then you can fetch the records again.

**Keeping the statement in scope**

@Glenn's comment is extremely important. The way your program works right now, it may work fine throughout the testing phase, and then suddenly in production, you'll sometimes have zero records in your `ResultSet`, and the error will be reproducible only occasionally - a debug nightmare.

If the `Statement` object that produces the `ResultSet` is closed, the `ResultSet` itself is also closed. Since you are not closing your `Statement` object yourself, this will be done when the `Statement` object is finalized.

The `stmt` variable is local, and it's the only reference to that `Statement` that we know of. Therefore, it will be claimed by the garbage collector. However, objects that have a finalizer are relegated to a finalization queue, and there is no way of knowing when the finalizer will be called, and no way to control it. Once it happens, the `ResultSet` becomes closed out of your control.

So be sure to keep a reference to the statement object alongside your `ResultSet`. And make sure you close it properly yourself once you are done with the `ResultSet` and will not be using it anymore. And after you close it remember to remove the reference you have kept - both for the statement and the result set - to avoid memory leaks. Closing is important, and relying on finalizers is a bad strategy. If you don't close it yourself, you might run out of cursors at some point in your database (depending on the DBMS and its configuration).